# How # flag in printf works?

Tags: c, printf

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  float x;
  x=(int)(float)(double)(5.5);
  printf("%#u",x);
  return 0;
}
```

How the `#` flag in the printf is working here?

Everytime I run this code I get different(garbage) values.

I know that the `#` flag works only with `o , 0x, 0X, e, E, f, g, G` but when it is not defined for integers.

So is this an *Undefined* behaviour? I am getting correct values when I am using the above flags.
So tell me whether I am right or wrong.

Comment: What is up with that chain of casts?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From c11 standard.

7.21.6.1. p6:

> #:
>
> The result is converted to an ‘‘alternative form’’. For o conversion, it increases
> the precision, if and only if necessary, to force the first digit of the result to be a
> zero (if the value and precision are both 0, a single 0 is printed). For x (or X)
> conversion, a nonzero result has 0x (or 0X) prefixed to it. For a, A, e, E, f, F, g,
> and G conversions, the result of converting a floating-point number always
> contains a decimal-point character, even if no digits follow it. (Normally, a
> decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit
> follows it.) For g and G conversions, trailing zeros are not removed from the
> result. For other conversions, **the behavior is undefined**.

So, to clarify, using `#` with `u` is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

From [the manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf):

> `#`
>
> The value should be converted to an "alternate form" [...] For other conversions, the result is undefined.

So yes, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Using this flag with any other than the listed conversions is undefined behaviour. Don't use it with other conversions.

> The value should be converted to an "alternate form".
>
> For **o conversions**, the first character of the output string is made zero (by prefixing a 0 if it was not zero already).
>
> For **x and X conversions**,  a  nonzero  result has the string "0x" (or "0X" for X conversions) prepended to it.
>
> For **a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and G conversions**, the result will always contain a decimal point, even if no digits follow it (normally, a decimal point appears in the results of those conversions only if a digit follows).
>
> For **g and G conversions**, trailing zeros are not removed from the result as they would otherwise be.
>
> **For other conversions, the result is undefined.**

(taken from the printf(3)-manpage. Wording is essentially the same as in the standard. Emphasis mine)